# Using a query in Microsoft Access to compare two fields and find multiple matching values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, duplicates

I have a problem I am trying to solve using a query instead of VBA.

I have two fields which we'll call "FPC" and "Code". Both fields contain numbers. An FPC value will match a Code value. What I want to make sure is that once an FPC value matches a Code value, the same FPC value does not match up with a DIFFERENT Code Value and vice versa - Once a Code Value is used, I don't want the Code Value to match up with more than one FPC.

It is important to note that there are duplicate values used in both fields.

Here is an example:

```
FPC         CODE
1            12
1            12
1            14
2            16
3            11
3            11
4            17
5            19 
6            16
```

There are two errors here:
1. The FPC "1" is matched up with two different Code Values.
2. The Code "16" is matched up with two different FPC values.

Please let me know your suggestions. I was thinking a query would help, and then running VBA to pull the results (there is tens of thousands of records).

Comment: So, for FPC 1, what Code value do you want, 12 or 14?  And vice versa for Code 16?

Comment: Hi Michael, it doesn't really matter which one. I don't want to change anything, I just want to raise an error because there are two different values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of the query? Just to identify problems? If yes then something like

```
select FPC, count(distinct(CODE)) from tableName where count(distinct(CODE)) >1 group by FPC
```

(and the converse query for CODE vs. FPC) should be OK.